# К чему нам [разработка]?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, удаление-метки

Зачем нам нужна метка [разработка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) ?

Все вопросы на SO так или иначе относятся к разработке, а значит, эта метка лишняя.

Comment: We don't need no [tag:разработка].

Comment: Чтобы удалить метку, достаточно убрать ее из всех вопросов. После этого, она автоматически удалится в течении суток.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky это обязательно делать руками? По идее автоматика могла быть изъять метку из всех вопросов, в которых эта метка не единственная.

Comment: Вроде бы да, надо все ручками править. Но говорят, что есть тайные знания, как сделать это автоматически. Попробую разузнать.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky получилось?

Comment: "0 вопросов по метке" - получилось или кто-то почистил? )

Comment: Получилось, Oded помог.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Предлагаю **убрать** эту метку. Она не несет полезной нагрузки и чрезвычайно широка — ей можно отметить 95% всех вопросов.

Comment: Да, также как [метка программирование](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3303/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5?cb=1).

Answer (score -5):

Полагаю, это общая метка для нетехнических вопросов (методологии, процессы и т. д.), поэтому её следует оставить.