# Надо же, [разработка] воскресла!

Tags: предложение, метки, удаление-метки

На мете уже был [пост](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3291/), в котором решили, что метка [разработка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) не нужна. Метку выпилили, а на пост повесили [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be). К сожалению, на данный момент [статус-не-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be). Метка воскресла, с ней уже 32 вопроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предлагаю выпилить эту метку снова!

Comment: Кстати, выделение областей на картинках тут принято делать [от руки](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/339911).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выпиливать метки - не очень эффективно, т.к. они будут появляться вновь и вновь. Для создания новой метки [достаточно иметь 300 реп](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags). Это достаточно низкий порог. А если она уже добавлена, то следом её могут лепить уже все подряд.

Если мы действительно хотим прикрыть лавочку с созданием бесполезных меток, такие метки надо явно запрещать. Если верить [ответу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298299/339911), список таких меток может быть сконфигурирован, но пока не ясно можно ли это делать применимо к отдельным сайтам SE.

В качестве полумеры метку можно оставить и кратком описании добавить "НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ ЭТУ МЕТКУ...". Такое уже практикуется на разных сайтах по разным причинам.

Кстати, есть ещё метка [разработка-по](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be). Смысл которой, имхо, тот же самый.

Comment: Никто не читает описание меток? люди просто их ставят.... и поэтому все "НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ" будет 0% эффективно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский кое-кто читает. А еще, видя такую метку, её могут убрать как раз после прочтения описания. Если описания не будет — её скорее всего оставят.

Comment: Миллион раз видел метки (не эту конкретно, в другие) с подобным описанием на вопросах . Всем пофиг))

Comment: А что было бы без описания? 10 миллионов? 100? Если текст есть - его МОГУТ прочитать и принять. А если отсутствует, то точно не прочитают.

Comment: На текущий момент (да и уж много лет) конкретно на текущем сайте людям пофиг есть описание или нет. Так что отсутствие описание никак не влияет на соотношение или вероятность  проставления меток...Люди ставят то, что считают подходящим им... просто быстро написав в поле слово...Тем более, как ты сам писал:  чтобы создать метку нужно всего лишь 300 репы. Поэтому худо-бедно начинающий на сайте чел просто напишет что взбредёт в поле метки в вопросе и уже ещё хлам готов. И для этого никакие описания читать не надо. Мне нужна "разработка", я написал, нажл enter и готово, а вы мучайтесь с описанием)

Comment: [разработку-игр] не трожте, это достаточно специфичная тема, и описательная сила у такой метки есть )