# Внести в чёрный список метки, удалённые за 2023 год

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, чёрный-список-меток

За этот год сообществом были удалены некоторые мета-метки. С ними было разное количество вопросов, от 9 до 550. Однако эти метки можно создать снова, поэтому предлагаю внести их в чёрный список. Это сделать возможно — например, недавно [внесли](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13107/532877) в запретный список [интернет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82).

Вот кандидаты в чёрный список,  уже удалённые за этот год (а некоторые из них удалялись несколько раз в прошлом), но имеющие шанс воскреснуть:

- [система](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0). Неясно, о чём метка. Об операционной системе? О системе исчисления? О файловой системе? [Писал подробно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12995/532877) про эту метку (и следующую в том числе) на мете. Специалистов по системам тоже быть не может. Поэтому метка была снята со всех вопросов, заменена более подходящими и должна быть запрещена.
- [system](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system). Это тоже неоднозначная метка. Это англоязычный аналог [система](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0)? Или про класс System в языках программирования? А, кстати, в каком языке? Тут та же [ситуация, что и с меткой [math]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13081/532877): из-за того, что название популярное, метка может быть много о чём. А если учитывать, что ещё и используется в смысле русскоязычной [система](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0) (то есть в совершенно любом смысле), то и говорить нечего.
- [разработка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) и [разработка-по](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be). [Решение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3291/532877) сжечь их было принято много лет назад и даже привели приговор в исполнение. В этом году они воскресли (уже не в первый раз) и [были снова удалены в этом году](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12712/532877). Надо запретить их, чтобы покончить с ними раз и навсегда.
- [software](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software). Удаляли [раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4338/532877), [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7041/532877) и в этом году три. Метка не несёт никакой пользы, см. предыдущие обсуждения.
- [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft). Удалили [раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3805/532877), удалили [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9244/532877), в этом году уже [три](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13003/532877). Уже давно обсудили, что не нужна. Нужно внести в чёрный список, чтобы более не появлялась.
- [команда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0) и [команды](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%8b). Опять же: неясно, о чём метки. Часто вопросы с ними были связаны с пакетными файлами, скриптовыми языками и так далее. Нет однозначного смысла, специалистов по ним быть не может.
- [приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f). [Писал про них на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13019/532877). Если [программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b) удалили, то и с приложениями нужно сделать то же самое. Кстати, на enSO метку [application](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application) [сожгли](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371416/yet-another-application-for-burnination).
- [яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81), её синоним [yandex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex) и [yandex-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-api). [Почему надо запретить](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13127/532877). **Кратко:** У Яндекса много сервисов и API. Вопросы с этой меткой были и про [яндекс-карты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b), и про [яндекс-поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba), и про [яндекс-браузер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80), и про [яндекс-диск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba), и про [яндекс-переводчик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba)... И это ещё не всё. Ещё аргумент: метку [google](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) (это тоже крупная компания с множеством сервисов) на enSO сожгли, а у нас запланировали сжечь много лет назад. Чем [яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81) лучше?

Comment: Все из этого не факт что нужно заносить в черный список, это инструмент на крайний случай. По многим и не было утвержденного решения на удаление. Может только microsoft и software действительно требуют этого. Нужно по отдельным темам заводить на самые проблемные метки, приводить более подробное обоснование и желательно сразу переводить на буржуйский для сотрудников.

Comment: *`"Специалистов по системам тоже быть не может"`* -- сильно сказано. А у моей жены в дипломе специальность -- "Инженер-системотехник". Может и для остальных меток кругозора не хватило?

Answer (score 2):

Добавление сущностей в чёрный список выполняется исключительно сотрудниками компании. Дополнительно есть возможность указать поясняющий текст, почему запрещённая сущность действительно запрещена, чтобы пользователи не восприняли это какой-то ошибкой работы сайта.

Т.о. в подобных предложениях стоит добавлять и ожидаемый текст подсказки, чтобы, когда дело дойдёт до имплементации, у сотрудника уже был готовый утверждённый сообществом список, для которого можно сделать Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V.

Из этого следует, что текущий вопрос можно рассматривать как некий каталогизатор для вносимых в список запрещённый сущностей, но рассматривать каждую сущность (и описание причины запрета) следует отдельно.